# Multiple Keyboards - Grab each stream - On Macs - How?

Tags: c++, macos, keyboard

I have multiple wireless keyboards on my Apple MacBook Pro. I am developing a cross platform application in C++ that requires knowing the stream of each specific keyboard.

Currently I can accomplish this on Linux through Dbus and glib. On Windows I use the rawInput API. On Apple, I looked at the Documentation, and they talk about using HID Manager, but it is deprecated (i.e. Carbon days), and well the example code doesn't seem to work any more. So far, I have yet to find a way to hook into the raw keyboard streams on Mac, before the OS clumps it all as one.

Anyone have any ideas, or code examples to get the streams from multiple keyboards on a Mac?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to read the raw HID events coming from each keyboard using the USB [HID Manager](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/devicedrivers/conceptual/HID/intro/intro.html), but I'm not sure that will work (it seems like a big security hole if ordinary apps could read raw keyboard events, sniff passwords, etc.). You might need to run your app as root to access those input devices, if it's possible at all. HID Manager isn't too bad to work with but it's not documented all that well, [hidapi](https://github.com/signal11/hidapi) is a very nice cross-platform API that sits on top of it. Even if it might not expose all the features you need, it's still a nice example to look at for HID Manager programming.

The next level where you could capture keyboard events would be with [Quartz Event Taps](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003550-CH202-317057), and a `kCGHIDEventTap`. From looking at those docs though, I don't think there's a way to obtain events per-device.